# Localization / Internationalization Automation for XCode at Project/file Level for all Strings/ Numbers/ Units at once

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localization, internationalization

There are several plugins available which helps to make Localizable strings entries easily. Like: [extract-localizable-string-plugin-xcode](https://github.com/viniciusmo/extract-localizable-string-plugin-xcode)

My question is different from that.

Is there any automated tool/software which is capable of identifying all the - Strings/ Numbers / Currency - Units declarations at file or project level & help preparing Localization file in some effective (time saving) manner?

> For example: Let's say i have 5 string declarations at file1 & few
>   more at file2. I want to have those strings automatically detected
>   (extracted someway) & then added to Localized.strings file for
>   Language support. Is it possible?

Basically i want to extract all such string/ numbers, etc.. static declarations from project & apply localization support. I know it can be done manually but would be great if there are any automated ways to achieve this. Any help would be great.

At least any script or something which can help generating report or something which **lists down all the variables / titles, etc (Strings/ Numbers/ Currency / Units) to be used in localization file** would also help.

Comment: Is there any XCode Plug-in available which extracts all such Localizable content from entire project?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the service my team built over at [El Loco](http://elloco.com). It does exactly what you are describing and much more. There is a free tier available, so give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will check on it.

Comment: Is there any XCode Plug-in available which extracts all such Localizable content from entire project?

Comment: Are you asking in general, or specifically about El Loco? We decided not to go the plugin route at El Loco because it gave us greater flexibility both in terms of what we could do for Xcode / iOS (without depending on undocumented and unsupported API) and also in terms of our ability to reuse the work done for iOS for other mobile platforms.

Comment: Thanks Michael. El Loco is really good. Though my question was in general. Any tool/plug in or smart approach which helps extracting all the Strings, Numbers & Currency (especially this one which seems tough) from entire project file by file. That would really help if such xcode plug in is available.